# List number of family members with counters

Tags: grammar, counters

I learnt that to say:

> *I have two younger brothers and one younger sister?*

in Japanese, I can use:

> *弟と妹が二人います。* (Otōto to imōto ga futari imasu).

The grammar structure is the following:

> *Noun + が + counter (for people) + います*

But now I'm having trouble with this sentence:

> *I have **two** younger brothers and **two** younger sisters?* (Note: both nouns are plural).

Will the following sentence be correct:

> *弟が二人と妹が二人います。* (Otōto ga futari to imōto ga futari imasu).

Comment: "I have two younger brothers and one younger sister" = 弟と妹が二人います <-- Please can you check that this is what you meant to type?

Comment: It's my typo, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the structure:

> Noun + が + counter (for people) + います

You can combine two clauses like this (have you already learned this before?)

> 弟が二人いて、妹が二人います。

It's also possible to phrase it like this:

> counter (for people) + の + Noun + が + います

So that it becomes:

> 二人の弟と二人の妹がいます。